# hello, I have a problem with the api rest get on ionic 5

Tags: angular, rest, ionic-framework

**This is my home.page.html**

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
 <ion-toolbar>
  <ion-title>
   get
  </ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>enter code here

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
 <ion-row>
  <ion-col >
  <ion-button  color="success" (click) ="validarGet()" >
    Enviar Get1
  </ion-button>
 </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
 <p>sdfsdgsdfsd</p>
 </ion-content>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { DatosService } from './../services/datos.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage {
datos: any;
constructor( private datosService: DatosService) {}
 validarGet(){
   console.log('paso 0');
  this.datosService.getDatos()
  .then(data => {
  this.datos = data;
  console.log(this.datos);

  alert(this.datos);
  })
  }
 }
```

**and my provider**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatosService {

 url: string = 'http://190.196.222.212:8080/AppComertech/rest/Servicio/';
 constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

  getDatos(){

 return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get(this.url + 'prueba2?varX=askjd&varY=alkf')
   .subscribe(data => {
    resolve(data);
    alert(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
    alert(err);
  });
  });

  }
  }
```

**so, i cant show something in my device, I only get the alert (err) ;, to show on the cell phone, I have searched, and I have seen more pages consuming a method get, but everywhere it is the same code and I can not show anything**

**http://190.196.222.212:8080/AppComertech/rest/Servicio/prueba2?varX=askjd&varY=alkf**

[the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCEKS.png)

Comment: What happens if you put http://190.196.222.212:8080/AppComertech/rest/Servicio/prueba2?varX=askjd&varY=alkf in your browser on your phone? Most likely the request is being blocked.

Comment: it shows me the same

Comment: It shows you the same what? If you put that URL directly into your browser you can't possibly see that alert as that code doesn't exist. Are you able to see what the network is sending back?

Comment: the rest i occupying works

Answer (score 0):

As your console shows: your API is not setup to allow your client to make calls. The server needs to enable CORS.

However, you're off on a few things. HttpClient returns an observable so there's no reason to create a new promise. You also should not call subscribe on that observable inside your service as you won't do anything with the result inside the service.

```
// service
getDatos(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.url + 'prueba2?varX=askjd&varY=alkf');
}

// component
this.datosService.getDatos()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.datos = data;
    alert(this.datos);
});
```

Comment: and this // service
getDatos(): Promise<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.url + 'prueba2?varX=askjd&varY=alkf');
}

Comment: show me this error Type 'Observable<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<any>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally

Comment: @Fabian I updated my response. It should return Observable<any> not promise. Your server isn't setup to allow client side calls. CORS needs to be enabled.

Comment: OK thanks. So the code is correct, but is it only possible to enable CORS?

Comment: man, could you help me how to enable the cors? 
I have searched and I have not found

Comment: That is a separate question. Just FYI you can't enable it on the front end. It has to be done by the API.